# RRC state machine with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

i would like to reproduce the RRC State Machine of the UMTS system, as the image in annex with Tikz. Can someone help me?

[image: RRC state machine]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a coloured box around this text?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this diagram?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: thanks for the advice Joseph. I asked the question in this way because I could not find in Internet a similar example that might suggest how to create this design. Since I am not very experienced in using TikZ, I can help in learning the best If I see the code created by the most knowledgeable people. I hope this can help other people in my condition. Best regards, Leo.

Comment: You can look at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net) where you will find some nice examples like: [Actor Transaction Diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/actor-transaction-diagram/) or [Inertial Navigation System](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/inertial-navigation-system/).

Answer (score 4):

You should involve yourself with the coding process by trying to come up with your own code first. After then, you can ask your question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). There are a lot of members in this site who are eager to help but many are not that eager to start writing from scratch. Also, learning to do it by yourself at first is a fun and, I believe, *rewarding* experience. If you have enough time, I advise you to read through the very detailed examples in the first pages of the [pgf manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

I borrowed some ideas from the links given in the comments so that you can compare the code below with the link given in the comment. Nowadays, there are a lot of ways you can draw this with `tikz`. One way is with the use of matrices. The code below uses mostly manual placement of the nodes. Try putting `%` before each line to see what each line does. Also, I have left the drawing of lines for you to experiment on. Try it and then come back when you encounter a problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,fit,backgrounds}
% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzset{sensor/.style={draw, rounded corners, text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2.5em},
         box/.style = {minimum width=16pt,minimum height=16pt,draw},
         idles/.style = {very thick,draw=violet,text width=6em, align=center, minimum height=12em, rounded corners},
         line/.style = {,>=latex,->,draw=blue!50}}
\def\blockdist{4}
\def\tdist{2.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\node (idle) [idles] {IDLE Mode};

\path ([yshift=1.5cm]idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=blue!50] (dch) [sensor] {CELL DCH};
\path (idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=orange] (fach) [sensor] {CELL FACH};
\path ([yshift=-1.45cm]idle)+(\blockdist,0) node [draw=yellow!50!green] (pch) [sensor] {CELL PCH};

% Draw connections between nodes
\draw [line] (dch.east) -- +(12pt,0) |- ([yshift=5pt]fach);
\draw [line] (fach.east) -- +(12pt,0) |- (pch);
\draw [line] (pch) -- (fach);
\draw [line] (fach) -- (dch);
\node (t1) [box,fill=blue!50] at ($(dch)!0.5!(fach)+(\tdist,0)$) {T1}; % You can create a style for the boxes used in this line and the next
\node (t2) [box,fill=orange!50] at ($(fach)!0.5!(pch)+(\tdist,0)$) {T2};

% Exercise: Discover how to place Connected Mode label
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \path (dch.west)+(-0.5cm,0.25cm) node (dchleft) {};
  \path (t2.east)+(0.5cm,0cm) node (t2right) {};
  \node [idles,fit=(dchleft) (pch) (t2right),draw] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: thank you very much, I will follow your valuable suggestions and I try to complete the picture.