# Creating a finite state machine with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, circuitikz, overleaf

*Dear TEX Community,*

I want to create a state machine using `circuitikz` (not a state diagram), however I don't know how to go about it. Unfortunately, I can't find flip-flop like boxes which have more than three pins on the long side. Attached is a screenshot of the circuit to be created.

[image]

I apologize if this post seems a bit rushed and ungrateful, however I just started using LaTeX for studying. If you could give me a hint already, I can see if I can get ahead on my own.

*Thank you a lot!*

**EDIT:**
As I have not clue on how to do this, I can just give you the document header which already worked with drwaing another electrical schematic.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. What did you try so far, what problems did you encounter? We normally ask questions without niceties around it, it is not rude, only expected :)

Comment: @JuCa did this solve the issue? Thank you 

Comment: If my understanding of a state machine is correct, you will need `node`s to do your schematics and might not need `CircuiTikZ`. You can have a look at [the TikZ & PGF manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 50 for example. (There might be a more recent version of the manual, I  am not sure). You could also have a look at [RRC state machine with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84284/rrc-state-machine-with-tikz)

Comment: Additionnally, [SR Latch using Circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463369/sr-latch-using-circuitikz) can provide clarifications to draw flip-flop boxes.

Comment: I am so sorry. I forgot to add the screenshot.

Comment: In my opinion, I agree with @JuCa --- that is much more a block diagram than a schematic. You can use a generic chip as shown in "chip special usage" around page 136, but probably is a bit overkill